# "undefined symbol: TLSv1_method" error when import psycopg2

Tags: python

I installed psycopg2 by "easy_install psycopg2" on CentOS 5.3, no error was reported, but when I tried "import psycopg2", I got :

```
exceptions.ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2-2.0.9-py2.4-linux-i686.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: TLSv1_method
```

What might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to `yum install openssl`?